# how to Enum with Customized Value in Java?

Tags: java, enums

how can i create enum with some values in java and how to access for creating string in java

I tried to create enum like this but my ide is showing error

`Expected 0 argument but found one`

```
enum html
{
    VERTICALSWAPPINGMAIN("<div class=\"vertical-swapping\"></div>"),
    VERTICALSWAPPINGBODY("<div class=\"vertical-drag-drop\"> <p>PLACEHOLDER_LC</p> <span class=\"vertical-droptarget\" id=\"PLACEHOLDER_ID\" draggable=\"true\">PLACEHOLDER_RC</span></div>");
    
}
```

Comment: Oracle has a very good and exhausting tutorial on Enums: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: of course that 'll give errors if you don't provide a constructor for your enum

Comment: even i define the constructor it still display the same error

Comment: Show your code with a constructor and the exact error message

Comment: Ok now i got it, i need to use constructor passing string argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) at Oracle's, I'd try something like this:

```java
public enum VerticalSwappingHtml
{
    VERTICALSWAPPINGMAIN("<div class=\"vertical-swapping\"></div>"),
    VERTICALSWAPPINGBODY("<div class=\"vertical-drag-drop\"> <p>PLACEHOLDER_LC</p> <span class=\"vertical-droptarget\" id=\"PLACEHOLDER_ID\" draggable=\"true\">PLACEHOLDER_RC</span></div>");
    
    private final String html;

    VerticalSwappingHtml(String html) {
        this.html = html;
    }

    public String html() { return html; }
}
```

Usage:

```java
String htmlString = VerticalSwappingHtml.VERTICALSWAPPINGMAIN.html();
```

Comment: String html, instead of string Html ;)

Comment: @Stultuske Yeah, my Java is rusty. Wrote C# for the last couple of years. Sorry 'bout that. `_html` is probably also not the best of choices.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Thx for the Edit! Appreciate it.